# RecyclerView - I can't add more than 1 line

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm with a problem to add more than 1 line(item) in my RecyclerView, the item overwrites the previous one when I tap the button, but if I create a List<> with data in hardcoded on onCreate, It works adding more than 1 line in the RecyclerView. Follow the code:

> ListChecklistAdapter

```
public class ListChecklistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListChecklistAdapter.ListChecklistViewHolder> {
    private List<Checklist> mChecklist;
    private Context mCtx;

    public ListChecklistAdapter(Context ctx, List<Checklist> checklists) {
        mCtx = ctx;
        mChecklist = checklists;
    }

    @Override
    public ListChecklistViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.item_checklist, parent, false);
        return new ListChecklistViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListChecklistViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.cbItem.setText(mChecklist.get(position).getDescricao());
        holder.cbItem.setChecked(mChecklist.get(position).isCheckado());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mChecklist.size();
    }

    public class ListChecklistViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.item_checkbox)
        CheckBox cbItem;

        public ListChecklistViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }

    public void refreshData(List<Checklist> item) {
        this.mChecklist.clear();
        this.mChecklist.addAll(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

> item_checklist

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/item_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:text=" "
        tools:text="Exemplo de item de lista" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.rcv_lista)
    RecyclerView rvLista;
    int valor;
    private List<Checklist> lista;
    private ListChecklistAdapter listChecklistAdapter;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_add_item)
    Button btnAdd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

    }

    private int cont() {
        return valor++;
    }

    public void novoItem(View view) {
        lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(new Checklist("Item " + (cont() + 1), true));
        loadRecycler(lista);
    }

    private void loadRecycler(List<Checklist> lista) {
        if (listChecklistAdapter == null) {
            Log.i("LOG", "IF");

            listChecklistAdapter = new ListChecklistAdapter(this, lista);

            rvLista.setAdapter(listChecklistAdapter);
            rvLista.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
            rvLista.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, 1));
            return;
        } else {
            Log.i("LOG", "ELSE");
            listChecklistAdapter.refreshData(lista);
            listChecklistAdapter.onAttachedToRecyclerView(rvLista);
        }
    }
}
```

> activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="teste.com.br.recyclercomcheckbox.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcv_lista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="novoItem"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="+ novo item"
        android:textColor="#009688" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Move lista = new ArrayList<>(); out of your novoItem method. Initialise it only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove this line `this.mChecklist.clear();` from your `refreshData()`  method.

```
public void refreshData(List<Checklist> item) {
    this.mChecklist.addAll(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: *the problem in your code is that every time you are setting new adapter* no, only first time - read the code ... *you have use listChecklistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();* it is called novoItem->loadRecycler->listChecklistAdapter.refreshData->notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: issue is creation of new list everytime

Comment: @Selvin did you check in his `public void refreshData(List<Checklist> item)` he is first clearing his whole list than adding new

Comment: its true @Selvin please check his adpter class to

Comment: @NileshRathod Clearing the existing list but adding all data which is received from `lista1`

Comment: @nomag if he clear old list than add new data that's why he loose his old data

Comment: @NileshRathod: Its design issue, depends where he want to keep old data.

Comment: @nomag i think not design issue

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks to solve! Really the problem was inside of the method "refreshData". So I deleted the this.mChecklist.clear(), and It works now! Thanks a lot, for everyone!

Comment: @NileshRathod Your answer is not correct as such right ?

Comment: Done @NileshRathod

Answer (score 0):

[@Nilesh Rathod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod) solved the problem! I just deleted `this.mChecklist.clear();` from the `ListCheckAdapter.java > refreshData()`
Thanks for everyone to help too!